# How would you end the loop once the sprite has touched the wall?

Tags: python, pygame

So I've been struggling for a while to do this. I want the main loop to end/ the game to end once the `player` hits the border of the screen but can't seem to figure out how I would do this. Here's what I have so far:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([25, 25])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.color = color
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def moveRight(self, pixels):
        if self.rect.x + pixels > 500 - 25:
            self.rect.x = 500 - 25
        self.rect.x += pixels

    def moveLeft(self, pixels):
        if self.rect.x - pixels < 0:
            self.rect.x = 0
        else:
            self.rect.x -= pixels

    def moveUp(self, pixels):
        if self.rect.y - pixels < 0:
            self.rect.y = 0
        else:
            self.rect.y -= pixels

    def moveDown(self, pixels):
        if self.rect.y + pixels > 500 - 25:
            self.rect.y = 500 - 25
        else:
            self.rect.y += pixels

# Color
red = (255, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500,500])

# Sprite List
sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Player
player = Player(red)
player.rect.x = 250
player.rect.y = 250
sprite_list.add(player)

notDone = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while notDone:
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            notDone = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player.moveLeft(3)
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
        player.moveRight(3)
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_w]:
        player.moveUp(3)
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_s]:
        player.moveDown(3)

    screen.fill(white)

    sprite_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

In my example, the `player` sprite can move up, down, left, and right. The character also cannot move past the border. Is there a way for the loop to end (as if a game over) once the sprite hits said border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to end the game when the player rect hits the screen's edge, then there's no point in correcting the player's position if the player goes outside. It would be easier to use `Rect.clamp_ip` anyway.

As for quitting the game, the easiest way is to put your main loop in a function and just `return` in case you want to exit.

To check if a rect (like the player's) "leaves" another rect (like the rect of the screen), you can use the `Rect.contains` function.

```
import pygame


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([25, 25])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def moveRight(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x += pixels

    def moveLeft(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x -= pixels

    def moveUp(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y -= pixels

    def moveDown(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y += pixels

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500,500])

    # Sprite List
    sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

    # Player
    player = Player('red')
    player.rect.x = 250
    player.rect.y = 250
    sprite_list.add(player)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while True:
        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]:
            player.moveLeft(3)
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
            player.moveRight(3)
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_w]:
            player.moveUp(3)
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_s]:
            player.moveDown(3)

        if not screen.get_rect().contains(player.rect):
            return

        screen.fill('white')

        sprite_list.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(60)

main()
```

Comment: Would this be possible without having the main loop inside a function? Or does it only work that way?

Comment: To use `return`, you'll have to use a function. Of course there other ways to break the main loop, like you do by setting a flag or by calling `sys.exit` or `quit` etc. But I prefer the function/return way because it works with nested loops, ensures nothing bad happens after event handling (a common mistake you see daily on SO is people calling `pygame.quit()` and then calling other pygame functions after that), and does exactly the one thing it should do (ending the main loop) without exiting the whole application. But in the end, it's up to you.

Comment: The problem with this is that when the game "exits", the screen doesn't close. Instead, the screen freezes entirely and I can't do anything except exit via the shell window. (I'm using Python IDLE to code this) Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: Oh, never mind. If I add `pygame.quit()` before the `return` function, then the game will exit without issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You usually don't need to call `pygame.quit()`; EXCEPT when using IDLE. I don't know why and I usually don't use IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

The `move`* methods of the `Player` class must return a Boolean value that indicates whether the player hit the wall. Return `True` if the player hits the wall, `False` otherwise:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def moveRight(self, pixels):
        if self.rect.x + pixels > 500 - 25:
            self.rect.x = 500 - 25
            return True
        self.rect.x += pixels
        return False

    def moveLeft(self, pixels):
        if self.rect.x - pixels < 0:
            self.rect.x = 0
            return True
        self.rect.x -= pixels
        return False

    def moveUp(self, pixels):
        if self.rect.y - pixels < 0:
            self.rect.y = 0
            return True
        self.rect.y -= pixels
        return False

    def moveDown(self, pixels):
        if self.rect.y + pixels > 500 - 25:
            self.rect.y = 500 - 25
            return True
        self.rect.y += pixels
        return False
```

Evaluate the return value in the application loop and set `notDone = False` if the player touches the wall:

```py
while notDone:
    # [...]

    hit = False
   
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]:
        hit = player.moveLeft(3)
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
        hit = player.moveRight(3)
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_w]:
        hit = player.moveUp(3)
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_s]:
        hit = player.moveDown(3)
    
    if hit:
        notDone = False

    # [...]
```

---

Complete example

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([25, 25])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.color = color
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def moveRight(self, pixels):
        if self.rect.x + pixels > 500 - 25:
            self.rect.x = 500 - 25
            return True
        self.rect.x += pixels
        return False

    def moveLeft(self, pixels):
        if self.rect.x - pixels < 0:
            self.rect.x = 0
            return True
        self.rect.x -= pixels
        return False

    def moveUp(self, pixels):
        if self.rect.y - pixels < 0:
            self.rect.y = 0
            return True
        self.rect.y -= pixels
        return False

    def moveDown(self, pixels):
        if self.rect.y + pixels > 500 - 25:
            self.rect.y = 500 - 25
            return True
        self.rect.y += pixels
        return False

# Color
red = (255, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500,500])

# Sprite List
sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Player
player = Player(red)
player.rect.x = 250
player.rect.y = 250
sprite_list.add(player)

notDone = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while notDone:
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            notDone = False

    hit = False
   
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]:
        hit = player.moveLeft(3)
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
        hit = player.moveRight(3)
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_w]:
        hit = player.moveUp(3)
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_s]:
        hit = player.moveDown(3)
    
    if hit:
        notDone = False

    screen.fill(white)

    sprite_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but for some reason when my player hits the border, it still doesn't return true.

Comment: @ApparentlyJory I've add the complete example code to the answer. The example is tested and works fine.